append() function does not work when trying to remove duplicates in json file - Python
I have one json file which has some duplicates based on a column called userid, and want to remove those duplicates using append() function so that it can output a new file with the same format as the original one.
Here is a json file:
    [
        {
            "userid": "7126521576",
            "status": "UserStatus.OFFLINE",
            "name": "Avril Pauling",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "None"
        },
      {
            "userid": "7126521576",
            "status": "UserStatus.OFFLINE",
            "name": "Avril Pauling",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "None"
        },
        {
            "userid": "6571627119",
            "status": "UserStatus.OFFLINE",
            "name": "Laverne Alferez",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "None"
        },
        {
            "userid": "1995422560",
            "status": "UserStatus.OFFLINE",
            "name": "098767800",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "None"
        }
    ]

The output file after removing duplicated userids should be:
    [
        {
            "userid": "7126521576",
            "status": "UserStatus.OFFLINE",
            "name": "Avril Pauling",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "None"
        },
        {
            "userid": "6571627119",
            "status": "UserStatus.OFFLINE",
            "name": "Laverne Alferez",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "None"
        },
        {
            "userid": "1995422560",
            "status": "UserStatus.OFFLINE",
            "name": "098767800",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "None"
        }
    ]

I have tried the following codes, append() function appeas to not working correctly; it only append the last item:
    import json
    with open('target_user.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        jsons = json.load(f)

    jsons2 = []
    for item in jsons:
        if item['userid'] not in json2:
            jsons2.append(item)
            
    with open('target_user2.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as nf:
        json.dump(jsons2, nf, indent=4)

A quick help is very appreciated.

Yes, because json2 contains dictionaries.  It does not contain strings.  You'll need to use a loop to look for json2[i]['userid'].  Or, store the IDs you have processed in a separate list.

This should do what you need:
import json
with open('target_user.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    jsons = json.load(f)

ids = set()
jsons2 = []
for item in jsons:
    if item['userid'] not in ids:
        ids.add(item['userid'])
        jsons2.append(item)
        
with open('target_user2.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as nf:
    json.dump(jsons2, nf, indent=4)


Tim Roberts, you are the best. I love this community very much!

You have a typo here: jsons2 json2
import json

with open('target_user.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    jsons = json.load(f)

jsons2 = []
for item in jsons:
    if item['userid'] not in json2:
        jsons2.append(item)
        
with open('target_user2.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as nf:
    json.dump(jsons2, nf, indent=4)

You define jsons2 but if item['userid'] not in json2: so, json2 should jsons2 here.
Try again with corrected code.
I don't have enough reputation to comments, so I answered.

thanks. But with correct spelling, my original codes dont work - it get the same content; no duplicates are removed. So Time's solution is working perfectly

This is not a correct answer.  The "if" is never going to match, because jsons2 contains dictionaries, not strings.
