Easy way of merging two json files without duplicates based on a column in Python
I want to merget 2 json files into one json file and remove all duplicated rows based on a column (second column). At the moment I merge two or multiple json files manually, then I use python codes to remove all rows with duplicated userid.
First json file:
    [
        {
            "userid": "567897068",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "btb appeal court",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "None"
        },
        {
            "userid": "6403980168",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "Ah",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "fearpic"
        },
        {
            "userid": "7104649590",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "áž˜áž¶áž“ ážŸáŸ’ážšáž¸áž˜áž»áŸ†",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "Abc130000"
        },
        {
            "userid": "5813962086",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "Sothea",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "SotheaSopheap169"
        }
    ]

Second json file:
    [
        {
            "userid": "567897068",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "btb appeal court",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "None"
        },
        {
            "userid": "111111111111",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "Ah",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "fearpic"
        },
        {
            "userid": "7104649590",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "Da",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "Abc130000"
        },
        {
            "userid": "555555555555",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "Sothea",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "SotheaSopheap169"
        }
    ]

merged file should be:
    [
        {
            "userid": "567897068",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "btb appeal court",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "None"
        },
        {
            "userid": "6403980168",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "Ah",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "fearpic"
        },
        {
            "userid": "7104649590",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "Da",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "Abc130000"
        },
        {
            "userid": "5813962086",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "Sothea",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "SotheaSopheap169"
        },
        {
            "userid": "111111111111",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "Ah",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "fearpic"
        },
        {
            "userid": "555555555555",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "Sothea",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "SotheaSopheap169"
        }
        
    ]

I have use the following codes to remove duplicates based on userid column in a json file I merged manually:
    import json
    with open('source_user_all.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        jsons = json.load(f)

    ids = set()
    jsons2 = []
    for item in jsons:
        if item['userid'] not in ids:
            ids.add(item['userid'])
            jsons2.append(item)
            
    with open('source_user.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as nf:
        json.dump(jsons2, nf, indent=4)

The above work well.
Is there an easy way of merging multip json files, and remove all duplicates based on a column before writing to a single output file?
Thanks

You could put them all in a pandas Dataframe, deduplicate on the field you want, then back to JSON

Looking at your history, it seems that you're asking this question again and again, why ?

it is not true, sir. I have asked today about csv file which has completely different data format from those in json file. I have tried the codes given on my other post as well, by updating some codes there; but they dont work

And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78322855/append-function-does-not-work-when-trying-to-remove-duplicates-in-json-file?rq=2 ? The solution works, so why do you ask for another one ?

azro, not sure you are Admin of this website; please double check it - it is different. That is a single file; my post is is about merging multiple json files and removing duplicates. Are you a developer, sir?

I'm no admin, but a developer for sure. And i'd say you should try to understand the code and make some tries by yourself, going frmo merging 2 files, to merging N files, isn't too hard

You know how to apply the logic on a list of dict (your items)
Now you want to apply it to a list (each file) of list of dict, so just add another loop around
Using dict.setdefault you can have a nicer and shorter code
import json
from pathlib import Path

files = ["file_1.json", "file_2.json", "file_3.json"]
result = {}
for file in files:
    for item in json.loads(Path(file).read_text()):
        result.setdefault(item["userid"], item)

Path("merged.json").write_text(json.dumps(list(result.values()), indent=4))


sorry for a late reply due to being busy with other things. I ll try your codes soon and will give a feedback. Thanks

Great work. Many thanks

I run your codes later with errors on this line:  for item in json.loads(Path(file).read_text()):

You just need to build a dictionary by looping over your input files.
Like this:
import json

files = ["json1.json", "json2.json"]

td = dict()

for file in files:
    with open(file) as fd:
        for d in json.load(fd):
            uid = d["userid"]
            if not uid in td:
                td[uid] = d

with open("merged.json", "w") as fd:
    json.dump(list(td.values()), fd, indent=2)

You could remove the conditional check (not uid in td) if you don't care which duplicate is removed

thanks, sir. I ll try to extend your codes.

Your codes has errors on this line: for d in json.load(fd):

both answers have similar errors with function json.load()

@JamesBlack if json.load is failing, it's because the file you're opening does not contain valid JSON

Thanks. You are right. Re-tested both codes, both are working very well. The issue is with Python itself; for any column, Name for example ("name": "áž˜áž¶áž“ ážŸáŸ’ážšáž¸áž˜áž»áŸ†",), it contains strange characters, both codes create very long string with forward slash like this: /

Therefore, I decided to merge json files manually, and use another script to remove duplicated userid. Many thanks for great community.
